# XSL grouping using attribute

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I've got some XML that looks a bit like this:

```
<Options>
  <Option OptionGroup="Safety">Driver Airbag</Option>
  <Option OptionGroup="Comfort and Convenience">Front Electric Windows</Option>
  <Option OptionGroup="Comfort and Convenience">Height Adjustable Drivers Seat</Option>
  <Option OptionGroup="Comfort and Convenience">Pollen Filter</Option>
  <Option OptionGroup="Comfort and Convenience">Privacy Glass</Option>
  <Option OptionGroup="Comfort and Convenience">Remote Boot Release</Option>
  <Option OptionGroup="Comfort and Convenience">Split Rear Seats</Option>
  <Option>Something else</Option>
  <Option>Yet another thing</Option>
  <Option OptionGroup="Paint or Trim and Upholstery">Metallic Paint</Option>
  <Option OptionGroup="Exterior Equipment">Power Assisted Steering (PAS)</Option>
  <Option OptionGroup="Interior Equipment">Leather Steering Wheel</Option>
  <Option OptionGroup="In Car Entertainment">CD Radio</Option>
  <Option OptionGroup="Security">Central Locking</Option>
</Options>
```

I'd like to group the output together using XSL 1.0, based on their OptionGroup attirbute, having any Options without an attribute listed at the end. Something like:

```
<table>
<tr><th>Safety</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Drivers Airbag</td></tr>
<tr><th>Comfort and Convenience</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Front Electric Windows, Height Adjustable Drivers Seat, Pollen Filter, Privacy Glass, Remote Boot Release, Split Rear Seats</td></tr>
<tr><th>Paint or Trim and Upholstery</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Metallic Paint</td></tr>
<tr><th>Exterior Equipment</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Power Assisted Steering (PAS)</td></tr>
<tr><th>Interior Equipment</th></tr>
  <tr><td>CD Radio</td></tr>
<tr><th>Security</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Central Locking</td></tr>
<tr><th>Other</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Something else, Yet another thing</td></tr>
</table>
```

I'm guessing this is all possible.

Comment: This is certainly possible, using a technique called "Muenchian Grouping". Exactly what format do you want the output in though? Text format or shown, or maybe HTML format?

Comment: Sorry yes it would be HTML. I've edited my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
      <xsl:for-each select="Options/Option/@OptionGroup[not(. = preceding::Option/@OptionGroup)]">
        <xsl:call-template name="OutputGroup">
          <xsl:with-param name="title" select="." />
          <xsl:with-param name="items" select="../../Option[@OptionGroup = current()]" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:for-each>

      <xsl:if test="Options/Option[not(@OptionGroup)]">
        <xsl:call-template name="OutputGroup">
          <xsl:with-param name="title" select="'Other'" />
          <xsl:with-param name="items" select="Options/Option[not(@OptionGroup)]" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="OutputGroup">
    <xsl:param name="title" />
    <xsl:param name="items" />

    <tr>
      <th>
        <xsl:value-of select="$title"/>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$items" />
      </td>
    </tr>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Option">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
      <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [grouping sample](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="default" select="'Other'"/>

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="ogroup" match="Option" use="string(@OptionGroup)"/>

<xsl:template match="Options">
  <table>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Option[@OptionGroup][generate-id() = generate-id(key('ogroup', string(@OptionGroup))[1])]" mode="term"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('ogroup', '')[1]" mode="term"/>
  </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Option" mode="term">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@OptionGroup">
          <xsl:value-of select="@OptionGroup"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$default"/></xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
     </th>
     <td>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('ogroup', string(@OptionGroup))"/>
     </td>
   </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Option">
  <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">, </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It transforms

```
<Options>
  <Option OptionGroup="Safety">Driver Airbag</Option>
  <Option OptionGroup="Comfort and Convenience">Front Electric Windows</Option>
  <Option OptionGroup="Comfort and Convenience">Height Adjustable Drivers Seat</Option>
  <Option OptionGroup="Comfort and Convenience">Pollen Filter</Option>
  <Option OptionGroup="Comfort and Convenience">Privacy Glass</Option>
  <Option OptionGroup="Comfort and Convenience">Remote Boot Release</Option>
  <Option OptionGroup="Comfort and Convenience">Split Rear Seats</Option>
  <Option>Something else</Option>
  <Option>Yet another thing</Option>
  <Option OptionGroup="Paint or Trim and Upholstery">Metallic Paint</Option>
  <Option OptionGroup="Exterior Equipment">Power Assisted Steering (PAS)</Option>
  <Option OptionGroup="Interior Equipment">Leather Steering Wheel</Option>
  <Option OptionGroup="In Car Entertainment">CD Radio</Option>
  <Option OptionGroup="Security">Central Locking</Option>
</Options>
```

into

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Safety</th>
      <td>Driver Airbag</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>Comfort and Convenience</th>
      <td>Front Electric Windows, Height Adjustable Drivers Seat, Pollen Filter, Privacy Glass, Remote Boot Release, Split Rear Seats</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>Paint or Trim and Upholstery</th>
      <td>Metallic Paint</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>Exterior Equipment</th>
      <td>Power Assisted Steering (PAS)</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>Interior Equipment</th>
      <td>Leather Steering Wheel</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>In Car Entertainment</th>
      <td>CD Radio</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>Security</th>
      <td>Central Locking</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>Other</th>
      <td>Something else, Yet another thing</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I went with the other answer in the end because the code was easier to implement in my current code. Not saying your code wouldn't work, I'm sure it would. But big thanks for the link about grouping. Think I'm starting to get my head round the theory.