# Would like to use XSL 1.0 to match every first occurance of a value in a particular node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I would like to match the first occurance of a specific node value and i am stumped.

I have tried `<xsl:when test="root/content/contentType = root/content/contentType[.='generic'][1]">` but it matches every occurance, as does `<xsl:when test="root/content/contentType[.='generic'][1]">`

I would like to end up with the output HTML below. The first item has a header but every item has a class of the same value.

Here is my XML.

Any ideas are very much appreciated.

XML:

```
<root>
    <content>
        <contentType>ingredients</contentType>
        <listItems>
            <item>Item 1</item>
            <item>Item 2</item>
        </listItems>
    </content>
    <content>
        <contentType>generic</contentType>
        <listItems>
            <item>Item 1</item>
            <item>Item 2</item>
        </listItems>
    </content>
    <content>
        <contentType>generic</contentType>
        <listItems>
            <item>Item 1</item>
            <item>Item 2</item>
        </listItems>
    </content>
    <content>
        <contentType>ingredients</contentType>
        <listItems>
            <item>Item 1</item>
            <item>Item 2</item>
        </listItems>
    </content>
    <content>
        <contentType>directions</contentType>
        <listItems>
            <item>Item 1</item>
            <item>Item 2</item>
        </listItems>
    </content>
</root>
```

Desired Output:

```
<div class="ingredients">
    <h2>Ingredients</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="generic">
    <h2>Generic</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="generic">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="ingredients">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="directions">
    <h2>Directions</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

EDIT:

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:for-each select="root/content">
            <div>
                <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="./contentType"/></xsl:attribute>

                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="./contentType[.='ingredients'][1]">
                        <h2><xsl:value-of select="./contentType"/></h2>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="./contentType[.='generic'][1]">
                        <h2><xsl:value-of select="./contentType"/></h2>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="./contentType[.='directions'][1]">
                        <h2><xsl:value-of select="./contentType"/></h2>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
                <ul>
                    <xsl:for-each select="listItems/item">
                        <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>       

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you share your XSL with us?

Comment: Here is the XSL, which isn't as compact as I would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:for-each select="root/content">
            <div class="{contentType}">
                <xsl:if test="not(preceding::content[contentType = current()/contentType])">
                        <h2><xsl:value-of select="contentType"/></h2>
                </xsl:if>
                <ul>
                    <xsl:for-each select="listItems/item">
                        <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>       

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This might be a bit cleaner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="content">
            <div class="{contentType}">
                <xsl:if test="not(preceding::content[contentType = current()/contentType])">
                        <h2><xsl:value-of select="contentType"/></h2>
                </xsl:if>
                <ul>
                   <xsl:apply-templates select="listItems" />
                </ul>
            </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="listItem/item">
          <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

One discrepancy here is that your desired output has the h2 values capitalized, while they will not be in this case.  Were you aware of that?

I think the good practice would be to have the classes and titles as separate values in the source XML, but if you really want to use the same value in both places, you can capitalize the first letter by doing this:

```
<h2><xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(substring(contentType, 1, 1), 
   'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), 
   substring(contentType, 2))"/></h2>
```

Comment: Thanks this is great! I was aware of no caps, I just don't have it working in the xsl yet.

Comment: Great. Added my suggestions about the capitalization above.

Comment: Do you have any good references for learning xsl 1.0. Pulling test="not(preceding::content[contentType = current()/contentType])" out of your pocket is pretty impressive, at least it is to me.

Comment: I don't really know of any good tutorials or references except for the official XPath and XSLT specs: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/ http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/.  They're a bit arcane, but really clear up a lot of the confusion. Skipping duplicate values is a task that I've found to come up pretty often in XSLT. In fact, I answered two topics involving the same technique yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233776/xsl-grouping-using-attibute/14234746#14234746 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234682/xslt-xpath-for-each-path-specification-for-re-grouping-of-elements/14235597#14235597

Comment: And please have a look at whether my response to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14248719/1945651 solved your issue there as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are keen to learn more of the delights of XSLT, then you might be interested to know you can use a technique called "Muenchian Grouping" to solve this. Effectively you are grouping **content** elements by their **contentType** element, and taking special action for the first element in the group (i.e. giving it an **h2** heading)

Firstly, you define a key to represent your group

```
<xsl:key name="content" match="content" use="contentType"/>
```

So, you are looking for **content** elements, and arranging them by **contentType**.

Now comes the slightly scary part. There is how you check whether a given **content** element is the first element in the group for their **contentType**

```
 <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('content', contentType)[1])">
```

To break this down, `key('content', contentType)[1]` returns the first **content** element in the key for the current **contentType**. You then need to compare this with the current **content** element to see if they are the same. To do this, you use **generate-id** which returns a unique ID for any element.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="content" match="content" use="contentType"/>

   <xsl:template match="root/content">
      <div class="{contentType}">
         <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('content', contentType)[1])">
            <h2>
               <xsl:value-of select="contentType"/>
            </h2>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="listItems"/>
      </div>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="listItems">
      <ul>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
      </ul>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="item">
      <li>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </li>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For grouping problems, Muenchian Grouping is the most efficient way of solving the problem.